# Reload Page After returning to tab/window but only with x minutes

Tags: javascript

I'd like to auto refresh my homepage if the user switches the tab / window and then returns.
This works for the tab/window switching, but I'd like it to happen only every 5 or 10 minutes ...regardless of how many times the tab is switched during that time.

```
var hidden, visibilityChange; 
if (typeof document.hidden !== "undefined") {
  hidden = "hidden";
  visibilityChange = "visibilitychange";
} else if (typeof document.msHidden !== "undefined") {
  hidden = "msHidden";
  visibilityChange = "msvisibilitychange";
} else if (typeof document.webkitHidden !== "undefined") {
  hidden = "webkitHidden";
  visibilityChange = "webkitvisibilitychange";
}

function handleVisibilityChange() {
  if (!document[hidden]) {
      location.href = location.href;}
};

document.addEventListener(visibilityChange, handleVisibilityChange, false);
```

Any help appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create variable to know if user switched the tab then use `setTimout` in example below event will fire after 5 second

```js
var hidden, visibilityChange;
if(typeof document.hidden !== "undefined") {
  hidden = "hidden";
  visibilityChange = "visibilitychange";
}
else if(typeof document.msHidden !== "undefined") {
  hidden = "msHidden";
  visibilityChange = "msvisibilitychange";
}
else if(typeof document.webkitHidden !== "undefined") {
  hidden = "webkitHidden";
  visibilityChange = "webkitvisibilitychange";
}
var tabSwitched = false,
  leaveTime = 0,
  timerHandle;

function doTimer() {
  timerHandle = setTimeout(function() {
    doTimer();
    leaveTime++;
  }, 1000);
}

function handleVisibilityChange() {
  if(leaveTime === 0){
    doTimer();
  }
    
  if(!document[hidden] && leaveTime > 5) {
    console.log('leaveTime: ' + leaveTime + ' seconds, do action');
    clearTimeout(timerHandle);
    leaveTime = 0;
  }
  else if(!document[hidden] && leaveTime < 5){
    console.log('tab switched before 5 seconds');
    clearTimeout(timerHandle);
    leaveTime = 0;
  }
}

document.addEventListener(visibilityChange, handleVisibilityChange, false);
```

```html
<p id="wait">switch the tab and wait...</w>
```

Comment: Thanks.  This works, but it waits 5 secs before firing when the user returns.  I'm actually looking for it to fire as soon as they return, but not if they switched back and forth within 5 seconds.

Comment: Thanks!  Works well.